# Uniformly convergent sequence of nonzero analytic functions has nonzero or identically zero limit

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of nonzero analytic functions on a domain $D$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$. Show that if $f$ is not identically $0$ on $D$ then $f$ is nonzero on $D$.

Here is what I ultimately came up with after reading responses here:

Assume that $f$ is not identically $0$ but $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in D$. Then, there is a closed ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$ such that $\overline{B}(a,r)\subset D$ and $f(z)\neq 0\quad\forall z\in \overline{B}(a,r)\backslash\{a\}$. Since $\overline{B}(a,r)$ is closed and bounded it is compact and thus $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\overline{B}(a,r)$. Then, using the argument principle since $f$ is analytic by problem 8, $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\overline{B}(a,r)}\frac{f_n'(\zeta)}{f_n(\zeta)}d\zeta\rightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\overline{B}(a,r)}\frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta=0$ but this contradicts that $f(a)=0$ since then we would have $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\overline{B}(a,r)}\frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta=1$.

Comment: You should make some effort to show what you've already tried. By the way, you should be assuming the domain $D$ is connected.

Comment: You're right about the connected part, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Hurwitz theorem shows that $f_n$ and $f$ have same number of zeros in $D$.